# How can the child element's select value be selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get the selected menu value to show content. When I try to select the value `$(this).find('select[id^="requirement_type_]:selected').val();`, I'm getting back `undefined`.

Based on the value, I want the corresponding `id` div to `removeClass` of `d-none`:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $( 'div[id^="requirement_row"]' ).each(function( i ) {
        // requirement_row[{$row_number}]
        var req_parent_div_id = this.id;

        // get row id inside brackets
        var req_row_id_matches = req_parent_div_id.match(/\[(.*?)\]/);
        var req_row_id = req_row_id_matches[0];

        // get the rquirement type (training / certification)
        var req_type = $(this).find('select[id^="requirement_type_]:selected').val();

        console.log(req_type);
        // remove 'd-none' from selected requirement type
        // $('#' + 'requirement_' + req_type + '[' + req_row_id  + ']').removeClass('d-none');

        // remove 'd-none' class to show the requirement row
        $(this).removeClass('d-none');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="d-none" id="requirement_row[0]">
  <div>
    <select id="requirement_type_0">
      <option value="training">Training</option>
      <option value="certification" selected>Certification</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="d-none" id="requirement_training[0]">
    training
  </div>
  <div class="d-none" id="requirement_certificationg[0]">
    certification
  </div>
</div>

<div class="d-none" id="requirement_row[1]">
  <div>
    <select id="requirement_type_1">
      <option value="training" selected>Training</option>
      <option value="certification">Certification</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="d-none" id="requirement_training[1]">
    training
  </div>
  <div class="d-none" id="requirement_certificationg[1]">
    certification
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `:selected` pseudo-class belongs to the selected `option`, not the `select` element as a whole. But you don't need it, you can just get the value of the `select` to get the value of its selected option.

```
$(this).find('select[id^="requirement_type_]').val()
```

It would be simpler and more efficient if you used classes rather than ID prefixes.

```
    <select id="requirement_type_1" class="requirement_type">
```

Then you can use

```
$(this).find(".requirement_type").val()
```